# Formula of $\bigcap X$ when $X$ is a class

Tags: logic, set-theory

When $X$ is a set, I know we could define $\bigcap X$ as$Z$ such that $z \in Z \to \forall x \in X(z \in x)$

If $X$ is a class,  we may run into problem in the process of determining whether an element belongs to $X$. Thus, it seems to me it's not legitimate to write $\forall x \in X$. How could we overcome such difficulty?

**ADDED**: I want to show "$x$ is a natural number" is $\Sigma_0$ in [Levy hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levy_hierarchy)(a lemma without proof on page 28, Constructibility, K.J.Devlin). So I have to define natural number in the first place, which is the intersection of all inductive sets, but all inductive sets constitute a proper class.

Comment: Don't try to treat classes like sets. If you treat them like sets, they will get all the paradoxes that come with sets, and then we need something to contain the classes and sets.

Comment: Deleted the comment because I took inductive to mean contains something and is closed under under that operation, as I thought that was probably what was causing the op's confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a real difficulty. If $X$ is a formula then there is some $\varphi(x,p)$ such that for some fixed parameter $p$ we have $X=\{x\mid\varphi(x,p)\}$.

Now what is the intersection of a class, any class even a set? It is the collection of all elements which belong to all members of the class. So we write:

$$\bigcap X=\{y\mid\forall x(\varphi(x,p)\rightarrow y\in x\}$$

"Every element which satisfies $\varphi(x,p)$ includes $y$" (note that this is still our fixed $p$ from before).

One caveat is that if $X=\varnothing$ then this is not well-defined, at all. Vacuously $\bigcap\varnothing$ includes every element of the universe, but some authors require the elements in $\bigcap X$ to be elements from $\bigcup X$, in which case $\bigcap\varnothing=\varnothing$.

So as long as you know that there is at least one inductive set, the class $X$ of all inductive sets is non-empty and we can talk about its intersection well.

---

As for your difficulty, think of $\forall x\in X:\psi(x)$ as a shorthand for $\forall x(\varphi(x,p)\rightarrow\psi(x))$.

Answer (score 4):

This answer only deals with the added note in the OP.

An alternate way to show that "$x$ is a natural number" is expressible as a $\Sigma_0$-formula is to actually go through the work and do it.  The following will not depend on the Axiom of Infinity.  Note that $x$ is a natural number iff $x$ either $x = \emptyset$, or $x$ is a successor ordinal and all elements of $x$ are either $\emptyset$ or successor ordinals.  Now it is just a matter of going through the steps:

- assuming enough of ZFC, "$x$ is an ordinal" iff "$x$ is transitive and well-ordered by $\in$":

  - "$x$ is a transitive set" may be expressed as $( \forall y \in x ) ( \forall z \in y ) ( z \in x )$;
  - "all pairs of elements of $x$ are $\in$-comparable" may be expressed as $( \forall y \in x ) ( \forall z \in x ) ( y = z \vee y \in z \vee z \in y )$;
  - note that if all pairs of elements of $x$ are $\in$-comparable, then by Foundation (you need a small bit more, but not much) it will follow that $\in$ is a transitive relation on $x$;
  - by Foundation (essentially) $\in$ is an asymmetric relation on all sets;
  - by Foundation $\in$ is well-founded;
- "$x$ is a successor ordinal" is expressed as "$x$ is an ordinal $\wedge ( \exists y \in x ) ( \forall z \in x ) ( z \in y \vee z = y )$";
- "$x = \emptyset$ is expressed as $( \forall z \in x ) ( z \neq z )$.

Note that all of the formulas above are $\Sigma_0$, and so boolean combinations and restricted quantifications of these are also $\Sigma_0$.  Now just put all these parts together to express "$x$ is a natural number" as a $\Sigma_0$ formula.

Comment: It is neither necessary nor sufficient for $x$ to be a transitive set in order for $\in$ to be a transitive relation on $x$. (Exercise.)

Comment: @ZhenLin:  You know what?... you're right! [editing editing editing] Thanks.

Comment: Arthur, blame the kids. ;-)

Comment: @Asaf: It'll be my running excuse for the next 20 years I guess. ;)

Comment: @ZhenLin: Time for bed after one more edit. [Thanks for your attention to detail, which I seem to be lacking right now.]

Comment: @ArthurFischer It seems I can't get it quite correct either. _If_ $x$ is a hereditarily transitive set then $\in$ is a transitive relation on $x$, but the converse is not true. Blah.

Answer (score 2):

Note that writing something like $x\in X$ or $\forall x\in X$ is not in itself the major problem as element relations with a class (on the right side, of course) can be viewed as abbreviations for a more general predicate definig the class $X$.The problem is rather that what we try to define per
$$\bigcap X := \{x\mid \forall b\in X\colon x\in b\}$$
could be a proper class.

To be on the safe side, if $X$ is a nonempty class and $a\in X$, we might define
$$\bigcap X := \{x\in a\mid \forall b\in X\colon x\in b\}$$
and this is definitely a set. One must of course (readily) verify that this is well-defined, i.e. if also $a'\in X$ then 
$$\{x\in a'\mid \forall b\in X\colon x\in b\}= \{x\in a\mid \forall b\in X\colon x\in b\}.$$